# getting directory of a file without knowing its extension

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to present the photo of a user. That user may be of the type Doctor, Nurse or Patient and each person belonging to each of those types has a distinct ID which identifies him. I have the photos of each type of users separated in three folders inside the directory /images/user_upload/ and a given user may or may not have a photo. If he has a photo, I want to present the photo with a name which is the same as his ID (Note that I don't know the extension of this file, only the name). If he doesn't I want to present a default image.  I have a function called printUserPhoto for this end.

```
function printUserPhoto()
{
    $path = '/images/user_upload/' .ucfirst($_SESSION['listtype']). '/' .$_SESSION['id']. '.*';
    $source = glob($path);  
    if(empty($source))
        echo '<img src="images/default_profile_img.png" />';
    else
        echo '<img src="',$source[0],'" />'; 
}
```

Although, I always get an empty array in the variable $source, even though the image exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `glob` works at the server filesystem level. You are asking it to look for a path starting at the root. `/images` most probably does not exist

Comment: Can you verify that `is_dir('/images/user_upload/' .ucfirst($_SESSION['listtype'])` is TRUE? You have an absolute path, but I'm guessing it should be relative.

Answer (score 0):

This way with glob

```
function printUserPhoto()
{
    $pathToDocumentRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path = $pathToDocumentRoot . '/images/user_upload/' .ucfirst($_SESSION['listtype']). '/' .$_SESSION['id']. '.*';
    $source = glob($path);  
    if(empty($source)){
        echo '<img src="images/default_profile_img.png" />';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="',$source[0],'" />'; 
    }
}
```

Maybe  limit the filetypes user can upload. With that you could do something like this:

```
function printUserPhoto()
{
    $pathToDocumentRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path = $pathToDocumentRoot . '/images/user_upload/' .ucfirst($_SESSION['listtype']). '/' .$_SESSION['id'];
    $file = "images/default_profile_img.png";
    if(file_exists($path . '.jpg')){
        $file = $path . '.jpg';
    }else if(file_exists($path . '.png')){
        $file = $path . '.png';
    }else if(file_exists($path . '.gif')){
        $file = $path . '.gif';
    }
    echo '<img src="' . $file . '" />';

}
```

Also as being said by @Phil you are now referring to the file system root / being absolute path not relative to your document root.